# ActiveX Control in 64 bit windows

Tags: c#, .net, activex, 64-bit

For 64bit OS, out C# App will use BeauGague ActiveX Control ([www.beaugauge.com](http://www.beaugauge.com)).
[image]

Compile successfully, but display error “HRESULT:0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)” when running.
What can I do resolve the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hosting PreviewHandlers on x64 gives REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374204/hosting-previewhandlers-on-x64-gives-regdb-e-classnotreg)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with x64 application and ActiveX control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282323/problem-with-x64-application-and-activex-control)

Answer (score 4):

It works in design mode because Visual Studio is a 32-bit program.  But not at runtime, in VS2008 and earlier the project is built to target AnyCPU.  Which gets you a 64-bit process on a 64-bit version of Windows.  Which cannot load ActiveX components that are only available as 32-bit DLLs.

It doesn't look like your vendor has done much lately to keep up with developments.  The workaround is simple: right-click your EXE project in the Solution Explorer window, Properties, Compile tab.  Change the Platform target setting to x86.  Which ensures that your program always runs as a 32-bit process.

Comment: It is not a "rokaround" per se- for most software running 64 bit makes zero sense, which is wy IE, and the office suite, are 32 bit (office is also 64 bit, but the word is "do not use it if you dont ahve to - mostly acess and heavy excel users), as it has no benefit.